# Calling SQL query in PowerShell fails

Tags: sql, powershell, stored-procedures, ssms

Executing SQL code in PowerShell fails. I have the following SQL I need to convert and call it in PowerShell.

*SQL*

```
USE [Test]
GO 

DECLARE @return_value INT
EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[WB_Open] @Description = N'WTS Entrance'

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
```

PowerShell ($SQLServer and $SQLDBName passed through function)

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$SQLServer;Database=$SQLDBName;Integrated Security=True"

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

$sqlCmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure

$SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@return_value", 1) | Out-Null  #not sure about this

$SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", 'WTS Entrance') | Out-Null

$SqlCmd.CommandText = "WB_Open"

$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter

$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd

$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

$SqlConnection.Close()

$DataSet.Tables[0]
```

I have tried the following (not experienced with this) with no luck, I'm sure it's my syntax but I've spent hours trying to figure this out with little luck - any help is really appreciated here!

Comment: why don't you try to write your executing code in a .sql file and try to run it through Powershell

Comment: I don't see a question here. In what way does it fail? Please provide a descrription of the issue. Your actual SQL doesn't look valid. Have you tried running it directly? Your last line should probably be `SELECT [Return Value] = @return_value`

Comment: What is the error with which it fails ? Can you provide the details ? Is it the database error exception or command exception ?

Comment: Expanding on @Esperanto57 comment, you're not running a stored procedure, your running a script which runs a stored procedure. Your Powershell think you are just running a stored proceudre.

Answer (score 0):

#### remove this line

#### $SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@return_value", 1) | Out-Null  #not sure about this

your result is in $DataSet.Tables[0]

Comment: Or leave the Powershell code as is and just call the stored procedure on it's own without all the wrapper code